# Site appearance unchanged after installing wooCommerce or WP e-Commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm an experienced Linux user, but have a limited WordPress experience (I admin a WordPress website with [ProPhoto](http://www.prophoto.com) plugin since 1 year for my wife).

Now I am trying to install a web shop plugin on a new WordPress 3.9 website.

I have tried [wooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) and [WP e-Commerce](http://getshopped.org) plugins and my problem is: the plugins install just fine, but the site appearance is unchanged.

So I go into Dashboard -> Themes thinking that maybe a new theme has been installed by the plugins and I just need to activate it - but there are only the core themes:

[image: dashboard]

I search for additional themes, but only see commercial ones, like "MayaShop". I do plan to purchase a commercial theme later, but first I'd like to try a "core" wooCommerce theme - to get used to this plugin.

How to find/activate/install the default wooCommerce theme please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce is only a plugin and won't change the appearance of your site.  You won't see any changes until you go to a product or checkout related page.
If you'd like to try a free WooCommerce enabled theme, there's a list here that can get you started: http://www.woothemes.com/2013/09/5-free-woocommerce-enabled-wordpress-themes-to-kickstart-your-business-online/

This article would also be a good resource to get you started: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-woocommerce-initial-setup--wp-29011